# Powershell store pipeline return value to variable

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell function which reads the status of my SQL agent job.

```
function get-SQLJobStatus
{
    param(
        [string]$server, 
        [string]$jobName
    )

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null

    $srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server($server)
    if($jobName)
    {
        $srv.JobServer.Jobs | where {$_.Name -match $jobName} | Select CurrentRunStatus
    }
}
```

If I run this function, the return looks like below

```
CurrentRunStatus
________________
Idle
```

What I want to do is run this `get-SQLJobStatus` function and check if `CurrentRunStatus == Idle`. It seems like I can't just store those return into the variable so I am stuck.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not? Show how you’re saving to variable and comparing. Should be as simple as if($variable.currentrunstaus -eq ‘idle’){“is idle”}

Comment: you are showing what looks like and object with one property [CurrentRunStatus] that has the value of `Idle`. so check it via `$Var.PropertyName`. [*grin*]

Comment: "_It seems like I can't just store those return into the variable so I am stuck._" - What kind of error do you get if you do `$result = get-SQLJobStatus someServer someJob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function returns an object with the `CurrentRunStatus` property, you can check it by using member access (`.propertyName`) from the returned function call:

```
if ((get-SQLJobStatus -server 'servername' -jobname 'jobname').CurrentRunStatus -eq 'Idle') {
    # the job is idle. run code here
}
else {
    # the job is not idle. run code here
}
```

If you want to store the output of the function call, you can still run a similar check as above:

```
$status = get-SQLJobStatus -server 'servername' -jobname 'jobname'
if ($status.CurrentRunStatus -eq 'Idle') {
    # the job is idle. run code here
}
else {
    # the job is not idle. run code here
}
```

---

As an aside, your `$_.Name -match $jobName` comparison can return multiple objects. This is because `-match` uses regex and your `$jobname` value is likely unanchored. To return an exact match, you could opt for `$_.Name -eq $jobName`.

Comment: `get-SQLJobStatus` can return an array, if jobName matches multiple jobs. In this case the `-eq` operator will return an array too. So the `if` block will be entered if at least one of the jobs is idle, contrary to the comments in your code.

Comment: Sure. The poster's intention appears to look for a specific job name.

Comment: Then he should use `-eq` instead of `-match` operator in his code. Your example code would return status of all jobs that have substring "jobname" in their name.

Comment: That's fine. Should I be explaining the poster is potentially doing the comparison incorrectly? In the example, one item is being returned.

Comment: Ok. I added a comment for that scenario.